# Ratios of corresponding sides?

Tags: geometry

I've always used the fact that the ratio of corresponding sides on similar shapes are always equal. However, I have never really understood why this is the case. Consider similar triangles for example. Are the ratios of corresponding sides the same due to trigonometric ratios? Or is there geometric proof for why this is the case?

Furthermore, is there a general proof or intuitive reason for why **all** similar 2D shapes must have the same ratio of corresponding sides?

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Similarity is same as scaling. Think it in terms of zooming in and zooming out. So that the ratio of lengths of corresponding sides must be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

In **Elements, VI**, Euclid opens with a definition:  “Similar rectilineal figures are such as have their angles severally equal and the sides about the equal angles proportional.” Thus, for Euclid at least, the ratios  of corresponding sides are equal by definition, i.e. their equality is part of what is meant by calling calling the figures similar.